# Can I show animation until my Activity loads?

Tags: java, android, animation

I was wondering if I can display some kind of animation until my activity loads. Because when I start my app , it takes about 5 seconds to see the Activity. Until it loads, a white screen is displayed (**refer to the image below**).

[image]

Can I do that ?

And if I can , how it should be done ?

Thanks you in advance.
Have a great day.

Comment: you can show a progressdialog--Loading animation for 5 seconds

Comment: But i don't know if it lasts 5 seconds on all devices , or just mine

Answer (score 0):

if you are downloading some data or u got ridiculusly large listview - you got other problems....

downloading data: reduce amout of data that is needed for app to work

listview - user freaking recyclerview

and if this is a legit problem - then you need some sort of listener(that indicates whenever job is complete) like Thread.join() and whenever that listener activates - it should go to another intent and kill last one (to kill you need to use finish();)

Comment: I initialize 6 buttons and requesting a runtime permissions. I think requesting the  permissions  may cause this.

Comment: if permissions are properly implemented - it shouldint cause any problems.

Comment: https://github.com/WithoutCaps/FileEditor/blob/master/app/src/main/java/site/withoutcaps/fileeditor/FileEditor.java there is really basic (kinda shitty) implementation of it. Time some of your methods and try to figure it out cuz its wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ProgressDialog` in `AsyncTask`

```
new YourFragment.YourAsyncTask().execute();
```

Use this library [sweet-alert-dialog](https://github.com/pedant/sweet-alert-dialog) for more animation Loading

```
class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    SweetAlertDialog pDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //show your dialog here
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new SweetAlertDialog(getContext(), SweetAlertDialog.PROGRESS_TYPE);
        pDialog.getProgressHelper().setBarColor(Color.parseColor("#fdc80b"));
        pDialog.setTitleText("Loading...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        //hide your dialog here
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pDialog.dismissWithAnimation();
        }
    }
}
```

}